# Upload a File with ng2-Uploader (Angular2) & .net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I need some help to upload a file with the ng2-uploader library & web API on Visual Studio 2015 .net Core, Angular 2 & Typescript.

[Here are the docs for how to use the ng2-uploader](https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-uploader#backend-example-using-plain-php).

The POST Request is okay but my controller returns `_null_`.

Here are my files:

***upload.component.ts***

```
import {
    Component
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-upload',
    templateUrl: './app/upload/upload.component.html'
})
export class UploadComponent {
    uploadFile: any;
    hasBaseDropZoneOver: boolean = true;
    options: Object = {
        url: 'http://localhost:65000/customersImport',
    };
    sizeLimit = 2000000;

    handleUpload(data): void {
        if (data && data.response) {
            data = JSON.parse(data.response);
            this.uploadFile = data;
        }
    }

    fileOverBase(e: any): void {
        this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
    }

    beforeUpload(uploadingFile): void {
        if (uploadingFile.size > this.sizeLimit) {
            uploadingFile.setAbort();
            alert('File is too large');
        }
    }
};
```

***upload.component.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="file" ngFileSelect [options]="options" (onUpload)="handleUpload($event)"
    (beforeUpload)="beforeUpload($event)">

  <!-- drag & drop file example-->
  <style>
    .file-over {
      border: dotted 30px red;
    }
    /* Default class applied to drop zones on over */

  </style>
  <div ngFileDrop [options]="options" (onUpload)="handleUpload($event)" [ngClass]="{'file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
    (onFileOver)="fileOverBase($event)" (beforeUpload)="beforeUpload($event)">
  </div>

  <div>
    Response: {{ uploadFile | json }}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

***upload.controller.cs***

```
[Route("[controller]")] 
public class CustomersImportController: Controller 
{
  private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;
  public CustomersImportController(IHostingEnvironment environment) 
  {
     _environment = environment;
  }

  [HttpPost] 
  public async Task<ActionResult> UploadCustomers(IFormFile file) 
  {
     var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
     try {
           if (file.Length > 0) 
           {
             using(var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create)) 
             {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
             }
           }
           return Json("File was Uploaded");
         } 
         catch ()
         { 
             return null;
         }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nobody yet? seams to be a server side problem

Comment: Is it possible your "uploads" folder doesn't exist on your backend? I just run into it and that was my problem...

Comment: Hey Man! How you did it to trigger the controller method with IFormFile parameter? My method isn't triggered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081395/ng2-file-upload-doesnt-trigger-the-controller-method-net-core-web-api

Comment: Hi, you can't do it with IFormFile such that. you should add IformFile [ ] file in controller and put "file" in the options of your uploader. It's not good enough cuz it's a bad implementation. you'll have better chances to implement your upload with the best library i've found : fine-uploader

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `IFormFile file` as parameter of your action, you can only upload one file, and the name of the parameter (the name of your input) must be 'file'. Unfortunately i don't know how to set it with ng2-uploader.

I suppose that you can use an array as parameter to upload multiple files.

I haven't used it with ng2-uploader yet but I will. I will keep you in touch :)

EDIT:
after playing with it a bit, you can set the field name in the options of your uploader, by default the name is `file`.
I upload only file by file and it work with `IFormFile file`, but if you want to upload multiple files i think that you just have tu use `IFormFile[] file`. And of course if you want to use `IFormFile[] files`, just don't forget to change the name in the options ;)